# Google sheets SCAN function

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the sheets to auto go down and give me quarters like this

```
1Q08
2Q08
3Q08
4Q08
1Q09
2Q09
3Q09
4Q09
1Q10
```

and etc, going down a column using one formula.

I think it is possible using the SCAN function, but having problems with it.

I've tried

```
SCAN("1Q08",B1:B9,LAMBDA(a,c,
  LET(
     quart, index(split(c,"Q"),,1),
     year, index(split(c,"Q"),,2),
     new_quart, if(quart=4,1,quart+1),
     new_year, if(quart=4,year+1,year),


     new_quart&"Q"&new_year
    )
  )
)
```

It's starting with a blank so it can't accumulate, but I put `1Q08` in the initial value. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=let(initial_,8,seq_,4,years_,3,
    tocol(reduce(,sequence(years_,1,0),lambda(a,c,{a;index(sequence(seq_)&"Q"&text(initial_+c,"00"))})),1))
```

- you may change the parameters `initial_`,`seq_`,`years_` as per choice

[image]

Comment: wow. sick. love it.