# Google sheets, trailing sum of last 4 quarters and year over year percentage change

Tags: google-sheets-formula

```
1Q08 1 
2Q08 2 
3Q08 3
4Q08 4 10 
1Q09 5 14 500%
2Q09 6 18 300%
3Q09 7 22 233.33%
4Q09 8 26 200%
1Q10 9 30 180%
```

How do I use one formula in `C1` and another in `D1` to produce an array in column C of trailing 4 quarters sum in column B, and a yoy comparison in column D?

I have been playing around with the scan function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525122/google-sheets-scan-function), but not sure if it is the right one to use.

general formula for `D5` right now is `B5/B1` then pasted down

---

I need an alternative answer to rockinfreakshow's answer. I need to wrap it into another formula, and it's giving me blanks after I do it using rockinfreakshow's answer, even after playing around with the offset. It's so weird.

This is what i got so far after, turning rockinfreakshow's answer into a named function, this is for GOING ACROSS, NOT DOWN, I need the final formula to go across:

```
=map(arr,lambda(Σ,
  if(or(Σ="",counta(index(arr,1,1):Σ)<4),,
        sum(offset(Σ,,-3,,4))
  )
))
```

If i let the other formula output the array first onto the sheet then use rockinfreakshow's answer, it works. However, if I wrap rockinfreakshow's answer around the other formula. It gives me a row of blanks. I think it is in the offset, but I think i just need to try different ways until it works.

I also tried to use `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` on the array first:

```
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(array)
   ,1,
   COLUMNS(array)
)
```

I have a different and formula for quarter over quarter percentage, this works as a named function `QOQ_DOWN`:

```
=let(
New_ar,{0;ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(arr,ROWS(arr)-1,1)},

map(arr,new_ar,LAMBDA(t,t_lag,
iferror(t/t_lag-1

))))
```

I can use it on an array across: `transpose(QOQ_DOWN(transpose(B1:B9)))`

Comment: 1, Is this for Sheets OR Excel?! 2, whats the general calculation(formula) used in Column D to see those percent numbers?

Comment: @rockinfreakshow hey man, just updated the question to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

***Cell_C1***:

```
=map(B:B,lambda(Σ,if(or(Σ="",counta(B1:Σ)<4),,sum(offset(Σ,-3,,4)))))
```

***Cell_D1***:

```
=map(B:B,lambda(Σ,if(or(Σ="",counta(B1:Σ)<5),,to_percent(Σ/offset(Σ,-4,)))))
```

[image]

Comment: you did it again. thanks. question: i don't understand the point of the `to_percent` function. if i take it out, i get the same number. it's not like the function can keep the number as a percentage, because i can change the format of the text. so why does that function even exist?

Comment: you have the choice to click the *%* symbol in the menu tab OR hardcode the *to_percent* thing within the formula whilst by default a column is not `%-formatted`

Comment: ok. one last question. how come I can't make this formula go across. I tried to transpose it for a row. this is for the same numbers but just going across in rows 1 and 2. `=transpose(map(transpose(A1:J1),lambda(Σ,if(or(Σ="",counta(index(transpose(A1:J1),1,1):Σ)<5),,to_percent(Σ/offset(Σ,-4,))-1))))` . also added `index` to make the function work on any array, it works without `transpose`.

Comment: try `=map(A1:J1,lambda(Σ,if(or(Σ="",counta(A1:Σ)<5),,to_percent(Σ/offset(Σ,,-4)))))` [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/MpoTMet.png). If you need the final output vertical, wrap the formulas as such `tocol(formula)`

Comment: you've been a huge help. can I buy you coffee to show appreciation? i see you don't have a donate link in your profile

Comment: got it. it's in the offset. thought transpose would take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
arr,G1:P1,
counter, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(G1:P1),1,1),
table, transpose({counter;arr}),
MAP(counter,LAMBDA(c,

if(c<4,,
   sum( QUERY(table,"select Col2 where Col1 >= "&c-3&" and Col1<="&c))

))))
```

this works.